# Can I cancel my Kuwait visa and have it erased from their system?

Tags: visas, filipino-citizens, kuwait

I have an entry visa in Kuwait I want to cancel because my name is misspelled on that visa, and the employer didn't take any action almost 3 months ago. They cannot issue me a new visa because of that existing visa. This entry visa is out July 5, 2016, entry visa would only have 90 days. If this entry visa will expire it would erase in the system of ministry of interior in Kuwait?

Comment: Why do you wan to cancel the visa instead of just not using it?

Comment: My name is wrong spelling on that visa,and the employer didn't do any action almost 3months ago, they cannot issue me a new visa because of that existing visa

Comment: Because the employer only could and the original visa do the action to cancel the entry visa.

Comment: There's no way you're just going to be able to erase a record of the visa in Kuwait's database like that. If they've issued you an invalid visa, you and/or your employer need to work with the Consulate to get a new one issued with the correct information.

Comment: Meaning even its already expired it will always appeared in there database that I have existing visa.

Comment: Once it expires, the database will show that you *had* a visa and that it expired without use.

Comment: Even its already expired.,still cannot issued me a new visa?

Comment: They are going to have to issue you a new visa, according to their rules and policies. Surely they have some mechanism for dealing with a spelling mistake. That's not something anybody other than the Kuwaiti authorities (possibly with the request and assistance of your employer) can do though.

Comment: that's great to know,but my employer didn't do anything to change my misspelled name in the visa that's why until now I cannot apply or to make it to obtain another visa.

Comment: My employer really not doing anything to change my visa status What should I do.

Comment: You should do it yourself, as several people already advised you.

Answer (score 1):

> I have an entry visa in Kuwait I want to cancel because my name is
>   misspelled on that visa, and the employer didn't take any action
>   almost 3 months ago. They cannot issue me a new visa because of that
>   existing visa. This entry visa is out July 5, 2016, entry visa would
>   only have 90 days. If this entry visa will expire it would erase in
>   the system of ministry of interior in Kuwait?

Any issue related to an invalid visa must be referred to your embassy. Rather than going there and booking an appointment upfront you should first go the embassy's website and check if similar problems have been encountered, if not call them, explain your problem and that might lead to an appointment with them.

Be aware that solving visa problems takes time and it will not be an easy process. Just try to get ahead of the administrative papers you need to complete.

Comment: I did.,it's really suprising me and that's the very useless call from the embassy I've ever made.. Really suprising why? They don't know anything regarding my situation,they supposed to have information about my problem but they just easily told me "I don't know"

Comment: Given the fact you must have had be given your visa from Kuwait, they should be the entity in charge of canceling it if needed... If you have had already used the visa you want to cancel I would understand why they cannot cancel it but you seem not to have used it...

Comment: Yes I do send back to them the visa for them to cancel or to re-correct my misspelled name, I didn't used the visa.,all I want to know is if that visa been expire is it still show or can search on their database.,if it so then I cannot get a new visa from them. And if it's that's case a solution is to cancel it.

Comment: I have rechecked online for a [similar problem](http://www.yabiladi.com/forum/erreur-dans-visa-88-3843323.html) and yes you get in touch with the ambassy and tell them about the mispelt name. They will schedule an appointment with you and may re-check your identity. Then, they will correct the current visa. I don't think that you can cancel it...

Comment: The visa is already expired.,entry visa only last for 90days. What's next I don't know now.

Comment: If the visa is no longer valid I really doubt they will be able to modify or cancel it. But they might have a procedure for that for similar cases...